# typescript autocomplete shows me 2x car but I only want one

Tags: typescript

I have 2 props, car and allStations.

if I press car. then I get again car.car as autocomplete but I only want one like this car.id, not car.car.id.

What I am doing wrong ?

```
 {([car, allStations]: { car: ICarDetails; allStations: { id: string; location: string; }[] }[]) => (
```

I am very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, your function's parameter is an array of objects, and you have [destructured](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the first two array elements as `car` and `allStations` — each of them represents one of the objects in the array:

```ts
type ICarDetails = Record<"make" | "model", string>;

const fn = (
  [car, allStations]: {
    car: ICarDetails;
    allStations: { id: string; location: string; }[];
  }[],
) => {
  // This is the first element of the array:
  car
//^? (parameter) car: { car: ICarDetails; allStations: { id: string; location: string; }[]; }

  // This is the second element of the array:
  allStations
//^? (parameter) allStations: { car: ICarDetails; allStations: { id: string; location: string; }[]; }
};
```

It's likely that either you either want to destructure just the first element's properties:

```ts
const fn = (
  [{car, allStations}]: {
    car: ICarDetails;
    allStations: { id: string; location: string; }[];
  }[],
) => {
  car
//^? (parameter) car: ICarDetails

  allStations
//^? (parameter) allStations: { id: string; location: string; }[]
};
```

...or that you wanted an object parameter instead of an array (and if this is a React component function, then you almost certainly meant to use an object type instead of an array):

```ts
const fn = (
  {car, allStations}: {
    car: ICarDetails;
    allStations: { id: string; location: string; }[];
  },
) => {
  car
//^? (parameter) car: ICarDetails

  allStations
//^? (parameter) allStations: { id: string; location: string; }[]
};
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgwgQwE4BELAQSwDYGcoC8UAShAMYD2SAJgDwBEAtggNYT1QA+UTF1E2egBoouYEkwA7AOYA+ANwAoRZUlioAM0mEoACkVQoAbTLIRCbNgDKGYJgpqAugC4oAbwOGoppK-jI0DBxcJS8oC2tbezVXNyhMalcxCRl5KGwKUzsHJPEpaTSAXyNHUKhixyFFAEpCWXdPAHpGqAAVAAtMfC6oYHboDUwkdQEIRghJYCgKDV7+8KQkBBBnTx9FZoA9AH5lQ2a2zu78PuhccgdqKFHxyenZ04Wllc8ImwRstQ3GncVCpRUDnUWgATDp9IYjG4fOZLO9PrhCi4GmEfH5EKh0Fg8GVDG8okDYvFEqI8ql0pkPtFcikCuUSmUKlVagR6h5DOstrtXnCCV8uX8AapgZIAMzgzzQszhXlUoGFWKeDnIdEBLHBXEyyJymLuYk0-JpDJZamk2lFBmeQrMuoo7zIb6-HnahGO3b-RRAA)

---

Part of the cause of confusion might be all of the syntax in the function signature. You can extract the type information and break it down into different [aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-aliases) to simplify the syntax in the function, which will help you focus on smaller parts of the overall data structure in isolation. Here's an example of one way to do that with your code:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJygXigJQgYwPYICYA8ARALZwDWERUAPlKdnhADZEA0UAzsAgJYB2AcwB8AbgBQoSFADKwOMF7Z+KKAG8ovPAC4uPAYNFRm2TAqX9d3PkKMBfCZPDQACgmxhOqteKhQzCLrwCBJ+cMzMcubKnLpRisoA2gC6Eg7i4jj83FAAZiqoABRqARzhkfIJ2Xa6bh6cAJQowuq+-ojiAPSdAHoA-BlhEfEWnF29A+lAA)

```ts
type Car = Record<"make" | "model", string>;
type Station = { id: string; location: string; };

type Props = {
  car: Car;
  allStations: Station[];
};

const fn = ({car, allStations}: Props) => {
  car
//^? (parameter) car: Car

  allStations
//^? (parameter) allStations: Station[]
};
```